# Angular Material Inputs display incorrectly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I update my Angular Material to version 15 and i have problem with inputs. Currently it display like this
[image]

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi" />
    </mat-form-field>
```

How i should fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with TailwindCSS, which sets all HTML elements `border-style` to solid.

This is useful to them, but lead to unwanted side effects when using other libraries.

To resolve that :

```css
  .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled)
    .mdc-notched-outline
    .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-left-style: none;
  }
  .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled)
    .mdc-notched-outline
    .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
    border-right-style: none;
  }
```